# iOS Swift: Constraints did not update on screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, constraints

evening,

I have a problem with a scrollview constraint.

This is my code:

```
// when the keyboard is shown, move up some elements
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

            // Bring up the scrol lview
            print(scrollViewBottomConstraint.constant)
            self.scrollViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height
            print(scrollViewBottomConstraint.constant)
            self.view.updateConstraints()
            self.view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
            self.view.needsUpdateConstraints()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            // Bring up the next arrow with animation
            self.nextButtonBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height + 8
            UIView.animate(
                withDuration: 1.0,
                delay: 0.0,
                usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
                initialSpringVelocity: 6.0,
                options: [.allowUserInteraction,
                          .curveEaseInOut],
                animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

the console print 0 and than 253, so the constraint constant is updated. But on screen I can't see the change and I have this log:

> [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x7fa041471bc0,
>   UIInputSetHostView) that has not been rendered at least once requires
>   afterScreenUpdates:YES.

Comment: Did u solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Weird, just view.layoutIfNeeded() after changing constraints should do the job.

try removing:

```
self.view.updateConstraints()
self.view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
self.view.needsUpdateConstraints()
```

Just:

```
 view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Try just this:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else{
       return
    }

    scrollViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height
    nextButtonBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height + 8
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: what about the? [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x7fa041471bc0, UIInputSetHostView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.